# How to get id from hyperlink onclick using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have hyperlink containing `class="candidate_type". I want click on a button 
and show the id of the anchor with the id of candidate_type.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#continue").click(function(){
            candidate_type = $(".candidate_type").attr('id');
            alert(candidate_type);
        });
    });
</script>

<a class="candidate_type" id="Employer">I`m Employer</a>
<a class="candidate_type" id="Consultant">I`m Consultant</a>

<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="continue" class="btn-new">Continue</a>
```

Thank You

Comment: Please provide current output and expected output.

Comment: it only shows `Employer` when I click on continue while I select `employer` or `consultant @JigneshM.Khatri`

Comment: What **exactly** do you mean by _"select"_? How are you selecting anything?

Answer (score 6):

You have more than one `candidate_type` elements, to get id of all elements you can iterate over it using `.each` as shown below

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#continue").click(function(){
            $(".candidate_type").each(function(){
              var candidate_type = $(this).attr('id');
              alert(candidate_type);
            });
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="candidate_type" id="Employer">I`m Employer</a>
<a class="candidate_type" id="Consultant">I`m Consultant</a>

<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="continue" class="btn-new">Continue</a>
```